# Replace specific middle part of url

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess

My current URL examples:
`http://domain.com/works/united-kingdom/greater-london/london/bedfordshire/`

Now, need to replace the "united-kingdom/greater-london/london/" part with "uk".

So it display like: `http://domain.com/works/uk/bedfordshire/`

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}
RewriteRule ^/works/united-kingdom/greater-london/london/(.*)$ /works/uk/$1
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

also tried

```
# Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# # Turn mod_rewrite on
# RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /works/united-kingdom/greater-london/london/$1
```

But cannot see any change in the browser.

Note: These urls are coming from GeoDirecotory Location Manager (premium) plugin.

**Edit note:** Sorry I was copy pasted wrong url for the 2nd example url, so I just edited the line of "So it display like: `http://domain.com/works/uk/bedfordshire/`"

Comment: That's not how HTAccess or rewrite rules work, think of it as "the browser asked us for X, but we're going to rewrite that to Y, then pretend  the browser requested Y when we handle it", it won't change the URLs WP generates, or the address in the browsers address bar. Redirects may be what you want. Have you asked the premium plugin authors support routes? It's overwhemlingly likely that in order to answer this question we will need to spend hard cash on acquiring that plugin

Comment: If `/works/united-kingdom/greater-london/london/bedfordshire/` is what your website currently links to, then you need to change how your webapp constructs the URLs - that isn't something you should be doing in `.htaccess`. (?)